# How to get assetic to update assets in dev enviroment in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have the issue that my assets, e.g. my sass and javascript, did not recompile on file modification. I installed I accessed them via symlink option and access the dev environment via  `localhost:8000`. I have to manually call `/app/console assetic:dump` for them to update.

How do I get assetic to watch for file modification?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
php app/console assetic:dump --watch
```

If you want to watch for file modifications. This will re-run assetic:dump in the background automatically for you.

And yes dont forget if you use dev then access your site via app_dev.php

And small note... when you use production environment then make sure you execute assetic:dump with --env=prod (without --watch as well)

Answer (score 0):

I realized I have to access the dev page with `app_dev.php`:

```
localhost:8000/app_dev.php/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev
```